# multiple environment for websites in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I am a newbie in Kubernetes.

I have 19 LAN servers with 190 machines.

Each of the 19 LANs has 10 machines and 1 exposed IP.

I have different websites/apps and their environments that are assigned to each LAN.

how do I manage my Kubernetes cluster and do setup/housekeeping.

Would like to have a single portal or manager to manage the websites and environment(dev, QA, prod) and keep isolation.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

I only got a vague idea of what you want to achieve so here goes nothing.

Since Kubernetes has a lot of convenience tools for setting a cluster on a public cloud platform, I'd suggest to start by going through ["kubernetes-the-hard-way"](https://github.com/kelseyhightower/kubernetes-the-hard-way). It is a guide to setup a cluster on Google Cloud Platform without any additional scripts or tools, but the instructions can be applied to local setup as well.

Once you have an operational cluster, next step should be to setup an [Ingress Controller](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress-controllers/). This gives you the ability to use one or more exposed machines (with public IPs) as gateways for the services running in the cluster. I'd personally recommend [Traefik](https://containo.us/traefik/). It has great support for HTTP and Kubernetes.

Once you have the ingress controller setup, your cluster is pretty much ready to use. Process for deploying a service is really specific to service requirements but the right hand rule is to use a [Deployment](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/) and a [Service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/) for stateless loads, and [StatefulSet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/) and [headless services](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#headless-services) for stateful workloads that need peer discovery. This is obviously too generalized and have many exceptions.

For managing different environments, you could split your resources into different [namespaces](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/namespaces/).

As for the single portal to manage it all, I don't think that anything as such exists, but I might be wrong. Besides, depending on your workflow, you can create your own portal using the [Kubernetes API](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/kubernetes-api/) but it requires a good understanding of Kubernetes itself.